# STRIPE NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, payment

I am trying to update a connected account so it can accept the terms of service and be able to create a payout. however, when I try to run the code in the console so it updates it doesn't update and that error regarding the ip address pops up. I am following stripe's documentation to update accounts.

I have tried not including ip into the tos_acceptance, but the ip is neccessary! 
I tried 'ip' and putting quotes around request.remote_ip

```
"acct_id_12345", {
  tos_acceptance: {
    date: Time.now.to_i,
    ip: request.remote_ip,
  },
},
)
```

the error that appears is:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for main:Object
```

Comment: What is the context of the code snippet? Is it a controller or model in a Ruby on Rails application, a Ruby script or just inside the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to name the request variable this is the final product:

```
  account = Stripe::Account.create({
      country: "US",
      type: "custom",
      requested_capabilities: ["transfers", "card_payments"],
      email: current_user.email,
      business_type: "company",
      company: {
        name: business.name,
        address: {
          city: business.city,
          country: 'US',
          line1: business.address,
          postal_code: business.zip_code,
          state: business.state,
        },
        phone: '3128880912',
        tax_id: '000000000',
      },
      external_account: {
        country: "US",
        object: "bank_account",
        account_number: params[:account_number],
        routing_number: params[:routing_number],
      },
      settings: {
        payouts: {
          schedule: {
            interval: 'monthly',
            monthly_anchor: 1,
          },
        },
      },
      business_profile: {
        url: business.website,
        mcc: 5734,
      },
      tos_acceptance: {
        date: Time.now.to_i,
        ip: '181.48.147.209',
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running the code somewhere where the `request` method does not exist, eg. outside of a controller.